# How to see the content stored in std::deque in Visual studio 2010 (debug mode)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, stl

For std::vector, the content can be seen using the following statement in watch window of Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode

```
(v._Myfirst)[startIndex], count
```

where v is a vector variable, count is a no.of value to be listed.

Like std::vector: Is there any method we can use to see the content stored in std::deque in Visual Studio 2010 (debug mode) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the setting I used to solve this issue. This setting is not only addresses the problem of not showing the content in std::deque container, it also started showing the content in other stl containers as well [Vector, Map, Set etc] in debug mode.

[I tested this setting only for **Visual Studio 2010 Professional** version installed with **Microsoft Visual studio 2010 Service pack 1**]

Step 1:
  Uninstall the **Microsoft Visual studio 2010 Service pack 1**
       - for my project work I don't really need the Service pack 1 so uninstalling service pack 1 will not cause any issue for my case.

Step 2: 
    Restart your system.

Step 3: This step is not necessary if you are not getting **Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt'.** Otherwise browse through

**Project Property -> Linker (General) ->** Change **Enable Incremental Linking to No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)**